# Table pagination with json data

Tags: jquery, json, pagination

I have added pagination for json data table.
How to add 1 2 3 in between previous next buttons for pagination
Complete code https://jsfiddle.net/py9rvfcp/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                var table =  $('#myTable');

                var max_size=userDetails.length;
                var sta = 0;
                var elements_per_page = 3;
                var limit = elements_per_page;
                goFun(sta,limit);
                function goFun(sta,limit){
                    for(var i=sta;i<limit;i++){
                    var tab='<tr><td>'+userDetails[i].Username+"\n"+'</td><td>'+userDetails[i].Firstname+"\n"+'</td><td>'+userDetails[i].Lastname+"\n"+'</td><td>'
                              +userDetails[i].Email+"\n"+'</td><td>'+userDetails[i].Address+"\n"+'</td><td>'+userDetails[i].Mobilenumber+"\n"+'</td><td>'
                              +userDetails[i].Age+"\n"+'</td><td>'+userDetails[i].Gender+"\n"+'</td></tr>';

                     $('#myTable').append(tab)

                    }
                }
                $('#nextValue').click(function(){
                    var next = limit;
                    if(max_size>=next) {
                    limit = limit+elements_per_page;
                    table.empty();
                    goFun(next,limit);
                    }
                });
                  $('#PreValue').click(function(){
                    var pre = limit-(2*elements_per_page);
                    if(pre>=0) {
                    limit = limit-elements_per_page;
                    table.empty();
                    goFun(pre,limit); 
                    }
                });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the following:

Change your html as follows:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-xs-4">
    <button class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12 bgColor" id="PreValue">Pre</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2  col-md-2 col-xs-4 nav">
    </div>  
    <div class="col-lg-2  col-md-2 col-xs-4">
    <button class="col-lg-12 col-xs-12 bgColor" id="nextValue">Next</button>
    </div>  
</div>
```

js:

```
     var number = Math.round(userDetails.length / elements_per_page);//get total page number
     for(i=0;i<=number;i++) {
      $('.nav').append('<button class="btn">'+i+'</button>');//append a button for each page
     }
 $('.nav button').click(function(){//bind a click event
       var start = $(this).text();//get the current page
       table.empty();//empty the table
       limit = 3*(parseInt(start)+1) > max_size ? max_size: 3*(parseInt(start)+1);//set the limit to max size if the limit is bigger then the max size
      goFun(start*3,limit); //populate the table
 });
```

demo:https://jsfiddle.net/py9rvfcp/4/

Comment: pagination is not working there.I want add perform pagination for those list of numbers also

Comment: that was not your question

Comment: I have one doubt,In my table now I am visiting second page now.When I click next button it should move from second page to third page right?But number buttons are working separately,previous and next buttons are working separately.Can you please help me to do this?Updated code https://jsfiddle.net/c354jnxm/

Comment: if you click on the page button 2 and then on button next it should display the 3th page

Comment: @user7397787 if you have any problems you can post another question