# How to do pagination of table data using the received JSON table data in client side without bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have received the table rows data in JSON form using PHP server pages and received the JSON table rows with each new search condition new table is displayed. But the problem is when i have more number of rows so i want to paginate it and also allow user to select the number of rows he want to see like 10, 20, 30.

In short, i want to achieve the following result:

if number of rows are 200 and user want to see to 25 rows at a time then 200/25 means (previous 1->2->3->4.....->8 Next) 8 numbers display at the top of table which allow user to jump to desired page and see rows.

[image: Image of till now work]

**UPDATE: You can check my latest work in this in below answer.**

I tried below things in my `loadtable.js` file as shown below. Also i am attaching both my server side PHP file `search.php` and client side script `loadtable.js` which is processing the JSON data and do the pagination task.

```
//###########################################
// Pagination code start
//###########################################

$("#pagination").attr('style','display:block;');

$("#pagination").html("<p1>Total number of records fetched: "+result.length+"</p1><h5 style='display: inline-block;float:left;width: 150px;'>Number of rows/page: &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;<select id='number-of-records-per-page' onchange='num_of_records(this)' style='width:60px;'><option value='10'>10</option><option value='20'>20</option><option value='30'>30</option><option value='40'>40</option><option value='50'>50</option></select></h5><br><br>");

$("#pagination").append("<div id='nav-pagination' style='float:left;'><a href='#'>&laquo;</a><a class='active' href='#'>1</a></div>");

var total_num_of_rows = result.length;

var number_of_rows_per_page = $('#pagination').find('#number-of-records-per-page option:selected').val();

console.log(total_num_of_rows)
console.log(number_of_rows_per_page)

for (i = 1; i < total_num_of_rows/number_of_rows_per_page; i++) {

     $("#nav-pagination").append("<a href='#'>"+(i+1)+"</a>");

}

$("#nav-pagination").append("<a href='#'>&raquo;</a></div>");

 //###########################################
// Pagination code end
//###########################################
```

The problem is i am doing pagination inside ajax success funtion `success:function(data){` which i think will be called once when the JSON result is received from the Server side. Also as i m beginner in ajax feeling difficulty to proceed. Please help.

Complete code of client side script `loadtable.js`

```
// This is script to load table based on filter section

$(document).ready(function() {

var delay = 1000;

// Campaign Submit Info
$('[name="search_submit"]').click(function(e) {

$('#load-csv-file-button').attr('style','display:none;');
$("#filterRecords").attr('style','display:block;');
$('#add_lead_info').attr('style','display:none;');

e.preventDefault();

var lead_owner = $('#filterformpost').find('#lead_owner_select option:selected').val();
var lead_status = $('#filterformpost').find('#lead_status_select option:selected').val();
var campaign_status = $('#filterformpost').find('#campaign_status_select option:selected').val();
var company_name = $('#filterformpost').find('#company_name_select option:selected').val();
var tech_area = $('#filterformpost').find('#tech_area_select option:selected').val();
var firm_size = $('#filterformpost').find('#firm_size_select option:selected').val();
var firm_type = $('#filterformpost').find('#firm_type_select option:selected').val();
var country_name = $('#filterformpost').find('#country_name_select option:selected').val();
var state_name = $('#filterformpost').find('#state_name_select option:selected').val();
var start_date = $('#filterformpost').find('#start_date_search').val();
var end_date = $('#filterformpost').find('#end_date_search').val();        

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "./server/search.php",
data: {
"lead_owner": lead_owner,
"lead_status": lead_status,
"campaign_status": campaign_status,
"company_name": company_name,
"tech_area": tech_area,
"firm_size": firm_size,
"firm_type": firm_type,
"country_name": country_name,
"state_name": state_name,
"start_date": start_date,
"end_date": end_date
},
beforeSend: function() {
$('.search_lead_filter_message_box').html(
    '<img src="tenor.gif" width="40" height="40"/>'
);
},

success:function(data){

var result = $.parseJSON(data);                       

$("#filterRecords").empty();

//###########################################
// Pagination code start
//###########################################

$("#pagination").attr('style','display:block;');

$("#pagination").html("<p1>Total number of records fetched: "+result.length+"</p1><h5 style='display: inline-block;float:left;width: 150px;'>Number of rows/page: &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;<select id='number-of-records-per-page' onchange='num_of_records(this)' style='width:60px;'><option value='10'>10</option><option value='20'>20</option><option value='30'>30</option><option value='40'>40</option><option value='50'>50</option></select></h5><br><br>");

$("#pagination").append("<div id='nav-pagination' style='float:left;'><a href='#'>&laquo;</a><a class='active' href='#'>1</a></div>");

var total_num_of_rows = result.length;

var number_of_rows_per_page = $('#pagination').find('#number-of-records-per-page option:selected').val();

console.log(total_num_of_rows)
console.log(number_of_rows_per_page)

for (i = 1; i < total_num_of_rows/number_of_rows_per_page; i++) {

     $("#nav-pagination").append("<a href='#'>"+(i+1)+"</a>");

}

$("#nav-pagination").append("<a href='#'>&raquo;</a></div>");

 //###########################################
// Pagination code end
//###########################################

var table='';

table = $("<table></table>");

table.append('<thead><th>#</th><th>Lead Name</th><th>Company</th><th>Email</th><th>Phone</th><th>Lead Owner</th></thead>'); 

table.append('<tbody></tbody>'); 

var i = 1;

$.each(result, function(key, value) {

    table.last().append("<tr><td>" + i + "</td><td><a target='_blank' href=./lead/index.html?lead_id="+ value['Lead_Id'] + " </a>" + value['FirstName'] + ' ' + value['LastName'] + "</td><td>" + value['Company'] + "</td><td><a href=mailto:" + value['Email'] + ">" + value['Email'] + "</a></td><td>" + value['Phone'] + "</td><td><a target='_blank' href=./account/index.html?user_id="+ value['LeadAddedBy'] + " </a>" + value['LeadAddedBy'] + "</td></tr>" );

    i = i + 1;                

});

table.after().append("<br><br>");               

$("#filterRecords").html(table);
$('.search_lead_filter_message_box').html('');

}           

});

});


});
```

Comment: can this be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42152944/table-pagination-with-json-data, but in this bootstrap is used

Comment: Why aren't you using bootstrap datatable the builtin functionality ? where you can perform server side paginationetc, everything you want

Comment: Becoz i had not used bootstrap since i begin my project and that's why i don't want to use in between

Comment: I pasted some of my problem in answer section if you solve them it would be great

Comment: @AkhtarMunir have you any suggestion in this

Comment: Well it's along code to check and verify your problem bro, No one read and review all of your code. Maybe someone will help you. I would do help if it was written in datatable.

Comment: @AkhtarMunir please see below answer i updated

Answer (score 0):

I tried and done paginated in JSFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/rinku16/hn3t9gz6/33/) using the JSON Data but the problem is now that it is not correctly working for the display of number of rows per page.

I made a separate function to process the JSON data and display the result.

But i am facing little issues as below:

1) Number of rows per page is not working properly, although i tried to change the value of `var elements_per_page = 3;`. I also want to select the user select option to see number of rows per page he want to see. as you can see below pic.

[image]

2) Also `overflow-x` style is not working properly as shown in below pic.

[image]

3) Also i want to use CSS `focus` property to know which page the user is `class=nav` of 1,2,3,4 button between previous and next.

JSON data at client side to paginate.

```
var userDetails = [

  {
    "Lead_Id": "66",
    "FirstName": "John",
    "LastName": "Doe",
    "Company": "Google",
    "Website": "www.google.com",
    "Designation": "Manager",
    "Linkedin": "www.linkedin.com\/john-doe",
    "Email": "johndoe@google.com",
    "Phone": "5125501553",
    "State": "Delaware",
    "Country": "USA",
    "TechArea": "Cloud computing",
    "FirmType": "Corporate",
    "FirmSize": "Less than 10",
    "LastContactDate": "2020-02-03",
    "NextContactDate": "2020-02-29",
    "LeadDescription": "This is lead description testing",
    "OwnerNotes": null,
    "SetReminder": "2020-02-29",
    "AdminNotes": "This is admin notes testing",
    "LeadStatus": "Planned",
    "LeadAddedBy": "28",
    "LeadAddedOn": "2020-02-03 16:28:26",
    "LeadUpdatedBy": null,
    "LeadUpdatedOn": null
  },

  {
    "Lead_Id": "67",
    "FirstName": "Tohn",
    "LastName": "Doe",
    "Company": "Microsoft",
    "Website": "www.microsoft.com",
    "Designation": "Manager",
    "Linkedin": "www.linkedin.com\/tohn-doe",
    "Email": "tohn@microsoft.com",
    "Phone": "123456",
    "State": "California",
    "Country": "USA",
    "TechArea": "Computer Networks",
    "FirmType": "Corporate",
    "FirmSize": "Less than 10",
    "LastContactDate": "2020-03-05",
    "NextContactDate": "2020-03-07",
    "LeadDescription": "This is test lead description",
    "OwnerNotes": null,
    "SetReminder": "2020-03-11",
    "AdminNotes": "This is testing admin notes",
    "LeadStatus": "Planned",
    "LeadAddedBy": "18",
    "LeadAddedOn": "2020-03-05 10:47:21",
    "LeadUpdatedBy": null,
    "LeadUpdatedOn": null
  },

  {
    "Lead_Id": "122",
    "FirstName": "Test1",
    "LastName": "User1",
    "Company": "NA",
    "Website": "NA",
    "Designation": "Tester",
    "Linkedin": "NA",
    "Email": "test1@test.com",
    "Phone": "7508023064",
    "State": "Chandigarh",
    "Country": "India",
    "TechArea": "Computers",
    "FirmType": "Corporate",
    "FirmSize": "Less than 10",
    "LastContactDate": "2020-03-05",
    "NextContactDate": "2020-03-05",
    "LeadDescription": "Testing Lead Description",
    "OwnerNotes": "Testing Owner Notes",
    "SetReminder": "2020-03-05",
    "AdminNotes": "This is testing admin notes",
    "LeadStatus": "Planned",
    "LeadAddedBy": "18",
    "LeadAddedOn": "2020-03-05 17:34:25",
    "LeadUpdatedBy": null,
    "LeadUpdatedOn": null
  },

  {
    "Lead_Id": "123",
    "FirstName": "Test2",
    "LastName": "User2",
    "Company": "NA",
    "Website": "NA",
    "Designation": "Tester",
    "Linkedin": "NA",
    "Email": "test2@test.com",
    "Phone": "7508023064",
    "State": "Chandigarh",
    "Country": "India",
    "TechArea": "Computers",
    "FirmType": "Corporate",
    "FirmSize": "Less than 10",
    "LastContactDate": "2020-03-05",
    "NextContactDate": "2020-03-05",
    "LeadDescription": "Testing Lead Description",
    "OwnerNotes": "Testing Owner Notes",
    "SetReminder": "2020-03-05",
    "AdminNotes": "This is testing admin notes",
    "LeadStatus": "Planned",
    "LeadAddedBy": "18",
    "LeadAddedOn": "2020-03-05 17:34:25",
    "LeadUpdatedBy": null,
    "LeadUpdatedOn": null
  },

  {
    "Lead_Id": "124",
    "FirstName": "Test3",
    "LastName": "",
    "Company": "NA",
    "Website": "NA",
    "Designation": "Tester",
    "Linkedin": "NA",
    "Email": "test3@test.com",
    "Phone": "7508023064",
    "State": "Chandigarh",
    "Country": "India",
    "TechArea": "Computers",
    "FirmType": "Corporate",
    "FirmSize": "Less than 10",
    "LastContactDate": "2020-03-05",
    "NextContactDate": "2020-03-05",
    "LeadDescription": "Testing Lead Description",
    "OwnerNotes": "Testing Owner Notes",
    "SetReminder": "2020-03-05",
    "AdminNotes": "",
    "LeadStatus": "Planned",
    "LeadAddedBy": "18",
    "LeadAddedOn": "2020-03-06 10:54:12",
    "LeadUpdatedBy": null,
    "LeadUpdatedOn": null
  },

  {
    "Lead_Id": "125",
    "FirstName": "Test4",
    "LastName": "User4",
    "Company": "",
    "Website": "NA",
    "Designation": "",
    "Linkedin": "NA",
    "Email": "test4@test.com",
    "Phone": "7508023064",
    "State": "Chandigarh",
    "Country": "India",
    "TechArea": "Computers",
    "FirmType": "Corporate",
    "FirmSize": "Less than 10",
    "LastContactDate": "2020-03-05",
    "NextContactDate": "2020-03-05",
    "LeadDescription": "Testing Lead Description",
    "OwnerNotes": "",
    "SetReminder": "2020-03-05",
    "AdminNotes": "This is testing admin notes",
    "LeadStatus": "",
    "LeadAddedBy": "18",
    "LeadAddedOn": "2020-03-06 10:54:12",
    "LeadUpdatedBy": null,
    "LeadUpdatedOn": null
  },

  {
    "Lead_Id": "126",
    "FirstName": "Test5",
    "LastName": "",
    "Company": "NA",
    "Website": "NA",
    "Designation": "Tester",
    "Linkedin": "NA",
    "Email": "test5@test.com",
    "Phone": "7508023064",
    "State": "Chandigarh",
    "Country": "India",
    "TechArea": "Computers",
    "FirmType": "Corporate",
    "FirmSize": "Less than 10",
    "LastContactDate": "2020-03-05",
    "NextContactDate": "2020-03-05",
    "LeadDescription": "This is test description",
    "OwnerNotes": "Testing Owner Notes",
    "SetReminder": "2020-03-05",
    "AdminNotes": "This is testing admin notes",
    "LeadStatus": "Planned",
    "LeadAddedBy": "18",
    "LeadAddedOn": "2020-03-06 10:54:12",
    "LeadUpdatedBy": "18",
    "LeadUpdatedOn": "2020-03-06 10:55:08"
  },

  {
    "Lead_Id": "127",
    "FirstName": "John",
    "LastName": "Doe",
    "Company": "Google",
    "Website": "www.google.com",
    "Designation": "Manager",
    "Linkedin": "www.linkedin.com\/john-doe",
    "Email": "johndoe@google.com",
    "Phone": "5125501553",
    "State": "Delaware",
    "Country": "USA",
    "TechArea": "Cloud computing",
    "FirmType": "Corporate",
    "FirmSize": "Less than 10",
    "LastContactDate": "2020-02-03",
    "NextContactDate": "2020-02-29",
    "LeadDescription": "This is lead description testing",
    "OwnerNotes": null,
    "SetReminder": "2020-02-29",
    "AdminNotes": "This is admin notes testing",
    "LeadStatus": "Planned",
    "LeadAddedBy": "28",
    "LeadAddedOn": "2020-02-03 16:28:26",
    "LeadUpdatedBy": null,
    "LeadUpdatedOn": null
  }

];
```

Below is latest script at client side.

```
// This is script to load table based on filter section

$(document).ready(function() {

var delay = 1000;

// Campaign Submit Info
$('[name="search_submit"]').click(function(e) {

    $('#load-csv-file-button').attr('style','display:none;');
     $("#filterRecords").attr('style','display:block;');
     $('#add_lead_info').attr('style','display:none;');

    e.preventDefault();

    var lead_owner = $('#filterformpost').find('#lead_owner_select option:selected').val();
    var lead_status = $('#filterformpost').find('#lead_status_select option:selected').val();
    var campaign_status = $('#filterformpost').find('#campaign_status_select option:selected').val();
    var company_name = $('#filterformpost').find('#company_name_select option:selected').val();
    var tech_area = $('#filterformpost').find('#tech_area_select option:selected').val();
    var firm_size = $('#filterformpost').find('#firm_size_select option:selected').val();
    var firm_type = $('#filterformpost').find('#firm_type_select option:selected').val();
    var country_name = $('#filterformpost').find('#country_name_select option:selected').val();
    var state_name = $('#filterformpost').find('#state_name_select option:selected').val();
    var start_date = $('#filterformpost').find('#start_date_search').val();
    var end_date = $('#filterformpost').find('#end_date_search').val();        

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "./server/search.php",
        data: {
            "lead_owner": lead_owner,
            "lead_status": lead_status,
            "campaign_status": campaign_status,
            "company_name": company_name,
            "tech_area": tech_area,
            "firm_size": firm_size,
            "firm_type": firm_type,
            "country_name": country_name,
            "state_name": state_name,
            "start_date": start_date,
            "end_date": end_date
        },
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('.search_lead_filter_message_box').html(
                '<img src="tenor.gif" width="40" height="40"/>'
            );
        },

        success:function(data){

            console.log('data:')
            console.log(data)

            userDetails = data

            var result = $.parseJSON(data);

            console.log('result:')
            console.log(result)                       

            $("#filterRecords").empty();

            //###########################################
            // Pagination code start
            //###########################################

            $("#pagination").attr('style','display:block;');

            $('#pagination').html('<div class="row"><div class="col"><button class="col" id="PreValue"><i class="ion-skip-backward"></i> Previous</button></div>  <div id="nav-numbers" class="col nav"></div>  <div class="col"><button class="col" id="nextValue">Next <i class="ion-skip-forward"></i></button></div></div>');

            paginate_json_data(result)

             //###########################################
            // Pagination code end
            //###########################################

            $('.search_lead_filter_message_box').html('');

        }           

    });

});


});

function paginate_json_data(userDetails){

$('.search_lead_filter_message_box').html('');



userDetails = userDetails

// var table =  $('#myTable');

var table='';

table = $("<table id='myTable' style='width:30%;'></table>");

var max_size=userDetails.length;
var sta = 0;

//here if i change 3 to 10 then number of rows some navigation 3 rows display and then 10 row is displayed.

var elements_per_page = 3;


var limit = elements_per_page;

goFun(sta,limit);

function goFun(sta,limit){

    console.log(sta,limit);

    table.append('<thead><th>#</th><th>Name</th><th>Company</th><th>Website</th><th>Designation</th><th>Linkedin</th><th>Email</th><th>Phone</th><th>State</th><th>Country</th><th>TechArea</th><th>Firm Type</th><th>Firm Size</th><th>Last Contact Date</th><th>Next Contact Date</th><th>Lead Description</th><th>Owner Notes</th><th>Reminder Date</th><th>Admin Notes</th><th>Lead Status</th><th>Lead Added By</th><th>Lead Added On</th><th>Lead Updated By</th><th>Lead Updated On</th></thead><br>'); 

    table.append('<tbody style="overflow-x:auto;"></tbody>'); 

    for(var i=sta;i<limit;i++){

        var tab='<tr><td>'+i+"\n"+'</td><td>'+"<a target='_blank' href=./lead/index.html?lead_id="+ userDetails[i].Lead_Id + " </a>"+userDetails[i].FirstName+' '+userDetails[i].LastName+"\n"+'</td><td>'+userDetails[i].Company+"\n"+'</td><td>'+userDetails[i].Website+"\n"+'</td><td>'+userDetails[i].Designation+"\n"+'</td><td>'+userDetails[i].Linkedin+"\n"+'</td><td>'+"<a href=mailto:" + userDetails[i].Email + ">" + userDetails[i].Email + "</a>"+"\n"+'</td><td>'+userDetails[i].Phone + "\n" +'</td><td>'+userDetails[i].State +"\n" +'</td><td>'+userDetails[i].Country +"\n" +'</td><td>'+userDetails[i].TechArea + "\n" +'</td><td>'+userDetails[i].FirmType + "\n" +'</td><td>'+userDetails[i].FirmSize + "\n" +'</td><td>'+userDetails[i].LastContactDate + "\n" +'</td><td>'+userDetails[i].NextContactDate + "\n" +'</td><td>'+userDetails[i].LeadDescription + "\n" +'</td><td>'+userDetails[i].OwnerNotes + "\n" +'</td><td>'+userDetails[i].SetReminder + "\n" +'</td><td>'+userDetails[i].AdminNotes + "\n" +'</td><td>'+userDetails[i].LeadStatus + "\n" +'</td><td>'+"<a target='_blank' href=./account/index.html?user_id="+ userDetails[i].LeadAddedBy + " </a>"+userDetails[i].LeadAddedBy + "\n" +'</td><td>'+userDetails[i].LeadAddedOn + "\n" +'</td><td>'+userDetails[i].LeadUpdatedBy + "\n" +'</td><td>'+userDetails[i].LeadUpdatedOn +"\n" +'</td></tr>';

     $('#myTable').append(tab)

    }

    $("#filterRecords").html(table);
}

$('#nextValue').click(function(){
    var next = limit;
    if(max_size>=next) {
    def = limit+elements_per_page;
    limit = def
    table.empty();
    if(limit > max_size) {
    def = max_size;
    }

    goFun(next,def);

    }
});

$('#PreValue').click(function(){
    var pre = limit-(2*elements_per_page);
    if(pre>=0) {
    limit = limit-elements_per_page;
    table.empty();
    goFun(pre,limit); 
    }
});

var number = Math.round(userDetails.length / elements_per_page);

for(i=0;i<=number;i++) {

    $('.nav').append('<button class="btn">'+i+'</button>');

}

$('.nav button').click(function(){

    var start = $(this).text();
    table.empty();
    limit = 3*(parseInt(start)+1) > max_size ? max_size: 3*(parseInt(start)+1)
    goFun(start*3,limit);

});


}
```

Comment: Remove `$(document).ready(function(){` this portion from your function `paginate_json_data` it may work for your pagination record. And for `overflow-x` try to apply this on table `<body>`.

Comment: yes that was good i don that but the horizontal bar i am not getting to scroll table horizontally. you just need a JSON to solve the problem of pagination function. I am updating the answer with JSON

Comment: also i want to use CSS `focus` property to know which page the user is

Comment: @AkhtarMunir overflow-x is not working, just delete some of code in latest file `loadtable.js` and use JSON data to rectify it.

Comment: @AkhtarMunir all problems are solved but the only thing is left that this `var elements_per_page = 3;` thing is not working properly you can check it from 3 to 10 by changing values and displaying the result but not displaying rows correctly.

Comment: Bro I am in office, and you have a bunch of code. If I am going to resolve it, then it will take time to review all of your code. I can't directly figure out actual problem in your code in a minute or two. Maybe in free time.

Comment: `$('#myTable').append(tab);` to `$('#myTable').empty().append(tab);` it may work.

Comment: I appreciate ur efforts but this `$('#myTable').empty().append(tab);` making single row at a time and not solving problem

Comment: can you check at this link https://jsfiddle.net/rinku16/tfsrnj8y/ here i on click of next button the css chaneg the focus to next sibling of the numbers between previous and next button.

Comment: @AkhtarMunir, can you see my all code at link https://jsfiddle.net/rinku16/hn3t9gz6/33/ and help in synchronization in previous and next button click with navigation button (1,2,3..) and pass the focus from on button to next and change the records